# Rejected edit 4137634 - what better approach?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

My [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4137634) was rejected, and I'd like to pursue self-improvement: why?

The suggested edit had two parts: indenting code; clarifying the error.  The former is arguably a minor one, but the rejection reasons tend to suggest that wasn't the main factor.

Was my introduction of the compiler's error message incorrect or unnecessary?  I can think of some potential reasons for thinking so:

- I don't know that this was the error message/compiler version used by the asker.
- It doesn't add anything: the question already adequately paraphrases the message.
- My edit comment didn't adequately justify the significant edit.

Should I instead have not suggested the edit (after all, the exact message didn't affect my answer), instead leaving it as a comment (which would still improve search visibility on the error)?  Or ignore it?

Comment: Your intentions were good, but as you say, you don't know what error message the asker is getting. The asker should clarify that themselves. Edits to code in questions are generally frowned upon because of the risk of introducing changes that could change the entire question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While its clear you were trying to improve this post this edit was rejected<sup>1</sup> because the reviewers could not be sure this was the error message the OP received. Their version may be different from yours or may be set up differently so they may not have received this error. Further you specified that the user was using version 4.8.2 which may not be true.

Suggested edits should rewrite the existing content to be clearer (your indentation was a good thing to do) but shouldn't add details that the OP themselves did not include.

So the following are good suggested edits:

- Indenting code
- Correcting spelling and grammar
- Editing in details from the OP's comments (be sure to include that you are doing that in the edit reason)

The following are bad suggested edits:

- Adding details that you have discovered yourself from your own investigations (such as this error message)
- Corrections to the code
- The answer to the problem (Included for completeness, I'm sure you know that)

<sup>1</sup> I can't know for certain this was the reason but it is highly likely.

## What you could have done instead

The correction of the indentation was good and I would say go ahead with that as is. The error message should be suggested as a comment, and if the OP confirmed it then editing it in would be helpful. This makes searching for the question much easier. If editing in from comments be careful to include "Details added from comments" to the edit reason or else reviewers may reject without understanding what you're doing.

Comment: The "4.8.2" was to emphasize the specifics of my "novel research".  So, two fails: your first "bad" bullet point and my false ascribing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the introduction of the error message was incorrect. As you said, you don't know which version of the software was used by the OP.
Furthermore, **you** decided that the extra information would be useful, not the OP. Since it is his/her question, and not yours, you should try to answer it, not change it in a way that alters its semantics (and your edit does, by loss of generality).
Your considerations would have been perfect as a comment.

Comment: To clarify, (for my "better approach") I should perhaps just have commented: "Using gfortran 4.8.2 I get the message ..."; or even, as it didn't change my understanding, left it alone?  If there's no confusion even the comment adds little.

Comment: @francescalus Adding that as a comment would have been helpful, and if the OP confirmed it then editing it in would be good. This makes searching for the question much easier. If editing in from comments be careful to include "Details added from comments" to the edit reason or else reviewers may reject without understanding what you're doing